# JavaScript Fetch Fails in Tauri-built App

Tags: fetch, tauri

I am building a small app using Tauri with HTML/JS/CSS. In the development, the app works exactly as I designed it. When I build the app, the app runs, but the buttons do not seem to work.

In the HTML, I created a button with a unique ID.

```
<button type="button" id="Song3@8@4"class="item" title="Song 3">Song 3</button>
```

In the JavaScript, I created an event listener that calls a function when the user clicks the button.

```
document.getElementById("playback").addEventListener("click", postForm);
async function postForm(event) {
    var clicked = event.target.id.split("@");
    fetch("http://192.168.xxx.xxx:8888/press/bank/"+clicked[1]+"/"+clicked[2], { method : "GET" });
}
```

The fetch URL is to a server running Bitfocus Companion. clicked[1] is to the page, and clicked[2] is to a specific button on that page. My taur.conf.json file has the sets the allowlist to all:true, the shell is set to all:false (default is false, but changing to true did not work), and open:true.

I do not know how to debug the app while it is running as an executable, instead of the developer mode. The app works exactly as it should and does not return any errors in development mode.

What changes do I need to make so the app works as an executable, not just in development mode?

Comment: in case you're using windows, the problem is the webview's mixed content policy, see https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri/issues/3007 - there are a few workarounds like the localhost plugiin for example.

Comment: @FabianLars, Thank you for the link. I am on Windows, and, after reading the link you provided, am sure that is my problem. I will try some of the solutions and see if I can get everything to work. Thank you.